# Ordering in SQL while using logical operators

Tags: sql, oracle, h2, sql-like

I'm trying to write an SQL query that has ***"OR"*** operator. The thing is that I want it to work with some, let say "priorities". I have an entity **Item**, it has two fields that I use in search:

- **description**
- **title**

And there is an SQL query:

```
select * from item
where description like '%a%' or title like '%a%';
```

What I want here is that if we have two entities returned and one of them matches like '%a%' by description and another one - by title, the one that matches via title should be the first one in the list. In other words, it should have bigger priority. Is there a way I can describe such a purpose in SQL?

***Dialect: Oracle / H2***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, you may use a `CASE` to order by a values that makes rows ordered by the way they match your conditions:

```
/* test case */
with item(title, description) as (
    select '__x__', '__x__' from dual union all
    select '__x__', '__a__' from dual union all
    select '__a__', '__x__' from dual union all
    select '__a__', '__a__' from dual
    )
/* the query */
select *
from item
where description like '%a%' or title like '%a%'
order by case
          when title like '%a%'
            then 1
          else 2
         end
```

This gives:

```
TITLE DESCR
----- -----
__a__ __x__
__a__ __a__
__x__ __a__
```

Comment: Thanks! That's perfectly works in my case! 
I use jpa2 criterias.
 Expression<Object> orderByExp = criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                .when(predicate, 1).otherwise(2);
        query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(orderByExp));